# placement new VS explicit constructor call in C++

Tags: c++, placement-new, explicit-constructor

recently I have come across these two ways of creating an object in a specific place in memory:

1.

```
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(T));
T* obj = new(mem) T();
```

2.

```
T* obj = (T*)malloc(sizeof(T));
*obj = T();
```

The second way is a bit shorter...are there other differences?
Regards
Mateusz

Comment: Even shorter is the correct one `T* ptr = new T();`. Please use that, and skip malloc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second way is wrong, the first is right.

You're invoking the assignment operator on a T instance containg garbage data. The assignment operator expects the instance to have been initialized correctly - It could e.g. delete member variables before assigning, which would cause all sorts of funny crashes. See e.g:

```
struct Foo {
  std::string * Data;
  Foo() : Data(0) {}
  Foo(Foo const & R)  { Data = new std::string(*R.Data); }
  ~Foo() { delete Data; }
  Foo & operator=(Foo const & R) {
    delete Data;
    Data = new std::string(*R.Data);
    return *this;
  }

};
```

The first way will ensure `Foo::Foo()` is called - thus properly initializing `Data`. The second way will lead to a `delete Data;` where `Data` points to some random location in memory.

EDIT:

You can test this the following way:

```
void* mem = malloc(sizeof(Foo));
memset(mem, 0xCC, sizeof(Foo)); // malloc doesn't guarantee 0-init
Foo* obj = new(mem) Foo();
```

And:

```
Foo * obj = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
memset(obj, 0xCC, sizeof(Foo)); // malloc doesn't guarantee 0-init
*obj = Foo(); // Crash
```

Comment: why garbage data? The *obj = T(); notation actually runs the constructor of T so it should be properly initialized I guess?

Comment: @Mateusz: No it doesn't. `T foo = T();` runs the copy ctor. `T foo; foo = T();` uses operator=.

Comment: so I understand that the situation is as follows: firstly, The T object is created on the stack, then it is copied to *obj with "=" operator and deleted afterwards, so all resourced dynamically allocated in constructor are deleted in destructor and not valid in *obj, right ?

Comment: in `*obj = T();` a temporary T is created on stack, and `operator=` is called. If `operator=` needs to do cleanup as part of handling the assignment it will do so on uninitialized data - which is demonstrated in an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
*obj = T();
```

This statement constructs a `T` object on the stack, and then does an assignment to `*obj`. It's wrought with unintended consequences.

On the other hand,

```
T* obj = new (mem) T();
```

This statement initializes a designated memory buffer, `mem`, by executing `T()` constructor method, as intended.

Comment: what consequences you mean? Actually, it doesnt even call the copy constructor of T - i did an experiment with copy constructor writing to std output and it didnt run on assigment

Comment: @Mateusz: it's assignment operator, not copy constructor.

Comment: So in the first case the object is created directly in "mem", and in the second case it's first created on the stack, then assigned to *obj, then the old one created on the stack is deleted  ?

Comment: @Mateusz: Yes. Now imagine if `T` has a pointer member variable that gets `delete`d on destruction, the same ivar in `obj` will be invalid!

Comment: OK! now I get it. Thanks, Santa!